# Which double bond is more electrophilic : carbon-carbon or carbon-oxygen?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

**Question**

[image: cyclopent-2-en-1-one and gilman's reagent with acid workup]

**Attempt**

It seems to me that the carbon-oxygen bond would be more electrophilic due to the higher electronegativity of oxygen. Hence I believe $\ce{CH3-}$ should attack the carbonyl site. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is it because that the intermediate carbanion can undergo resonance with oxygen, had $\ce{CH3-}$ attacked carbon- carbon double bond?

What can be a valid reason?

Comment: Google for gilmans reagenthttps://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2016/02/05/gilman-reagents-organocuprates-what-theyre-used-for/

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. You should have said "In a $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated system.." An isolated $\ce{C=C}$ bond is not electrophilic.

Comment: This may assist  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_of_organocopper_reagents

Comment: of course, C=C bond is less electrophilic when compared to C=O bond, but the CH3 group seems to attack the C=C bond due to 1,4-addition. detailed explanation below.

Comment: Here is useful info on Gilman reagents and conjgate addition: http://www-oc.chemie.uni-regensburg.de/OCP/ch/chb/oc5/Cu_Zn_Organometallics.pdf

Answer (score -1):

**step-1: cleavage of C=O bond**:

- the C=O bond undergoes heterolytic cleavage to give positive charge on carbon and negative charge on oxygen just like almost all other organometallic reagents react with a ketone, for example a grignard reagent (not exactly, but similar to it).

**step-2**:(the real step which caused deviation from your answer)-**resonance of intermediate**:

- the positive charge on the carbon of the erstwhile C=O group now undergoes resonance with the double bond at the allylic position to give positive charge at carbon no. 3 instead of carbon no. 1
- in this sort of reaction is 1,4 addition occurs instead of 1,2 addition. For more information, you can visit this link: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Ancillary_Materials/Reference/Organic_Chemistry_Glossary/1%2C4-Addition

**step 3**:(as usual):-**attack of CH3 group**:

- now on as usual, the CH3 group from our organo copper reagent ( called as gilmann reagent, used in Corey-house synthesis), just like a grignard reagent, attacks the new carbocation formed at carbon no.3 and the water molecule in the second step donates it's proton to the remnant oxygen of our old C=O group and it becomes an enol. tautomerisation takes place and we bet **3-methyl cyclohexanone** as a result.